# Unable to filter array-like object

Tags: javascript, lodash, domparser

I want to retrieve `[image]` tags in the HTML, therefore I use **`DOMParser`** to parse the string into an object. However I am unable to get the image array when using `._filter` by Lodash.

The strange part is that I able to get the result when using `._find`.

I've searched solution online but unable to find something relevant to my case, kindly enlighten me. Thank you.

```
const content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="keywords" content="seo, search engine optimisation, search engine optimization, search engine ranking"><meta name="description" content="A pages description, usually one or two sentences."/><title>Page title 123</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></head><body><h1>Hello there</h1><p><img src="https://fallbacks.carbonads.com/nosvn/fallbacks/731050e6bd3fc6979e1cb1a972294dae.png" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></p><a href="domain.com">This is domain</a><a href="domain.com2">This is domain2</a></body></html>';

let parser = new DOMParser(),
    parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/html'),
    tagsInHtml = parsedHtml.all;

// ## Filter the data
let hrefArray   = _.filter(tagsInHtml, { "tagName": "A" }), // ??? Empty [] array
    hrefArray2  = _.find(tagsInHtml,   { "tagName": "A" }), // This working;
```

Attached with the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ycxae4m/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your tags collection into an `Array` first:

```js
const content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="keywords" content="seo, search engine optimisation, search engine optimization, search engine ranking"><meta name="description" content="A pages description, usually one or two sentences."/><title>Page title 123</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></head><body><h1>Hello there</h1><p><img src="https://fallbacks.carbonads.com/nosvn/fallbacks/731050e6bd3fc6979e1cb1a972294dae.png" class="fr-fic fr-dii"></p><a href="domain.com">This is domain</a><a href="domain.com2">This is domain2</a></body></html>';

let parser = new DOMParser(),
    parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/html'),
    tagsInHtml = parsedHtml.all,
    tags = Array.from(tagsInHtml);
    
// Filter the data
let hrefArray = _.filter(tags, { 'tagName': 'A' }),
    hrefArray2 = _.find(tags, { 'tagName': 'A' });
    
console.dir(hrefArray);
console.dir(hrefArray2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: One thing i not understand is that, is tagsInHtml not an array? I see the item is wrapped by [ ].

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection - the `HTMLAllCollection` is an array-like object, not an actual array so it must be converted as such.